# How to fill UISegmentedControl Indexes with String Array Values in Swift

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UISegmentedControl with 4 indexes that contains quiz answers that are gathered from a string array.  My goal is to fill all 4 indexes with wrong answers, and then randomly replace one of those indexes with the correct answer.  When I run the simulator, the app appears to enter an infinite loop and the view never loads.  When I comment-out the entire second for-loop (which is supposed to fill the indexes with incorrect guesses), the view loads and the segmented control appears with just the correct answer displayed in one segment.  Why is the infinite loop being entered (if that is the case) and how can I modify this code to display the segmented controls as desired?

```
    func nextQuestion()
    {
        questionNumberLabel.text = String(format: "Question %1$d of %2$d",
            (correctGuesses + 1), numberOfQuestions)
        answerLabel.text = ""
        correctAnswer = allAnimals.removeAtIndex(0)
        animalImageView.image = UIImage(named: correctAnswer) // next animal

        // re-enable UISegmentedControls and delete prior segments
        for segmentedControl in segmentedControls
        {
            segmentedControl.enabled = true
            segmentedControl.removeAllSegments()
        }

        // place guesses on displayed UISegmentedControls
        allAnimals.shuffle() // shuffle array
        var i = 0        
        for segmentedControl in segmentedControls
        {
            if !segmentedControl.hidden
            {
                var segmentIndex = 0

                while segmentIndex < 4
                {
                    if i < allAnimals.count && correctAnswer != allAnimals[i]
                    {
                        segmentedControl.insertSegmentWithTitle(
                            getStringFromFile(allAnimals[i]),
                            atIndex: segmentIndex, animated: false)
                        ++segmentIndex
                    }
                    ++i
                }
            }
        }

        // pick random segment and replace with correct answer        
        let randomIndexInRow = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(4)))
        segmentedControls[0].removeSegmentAtIndex(
            randomIndexInRow, animated: false)
        segmentedControls[0].insertSegmentWithTitle(
            getStringFromFile(correctAnswer),
            atIndex: randomIndexInRow, animated: false)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
selectedSegmentIndex = 2
```